# How to deal with private keys in a messaging app without handing them to users?

Tags: security, encryption, encryption-asymmetric

I am trying to write a web application with chat system which stores chat messages in a mongoDB database on server side. I want my messages to be stored encrypted and sent across the web encrypted. Let's say I have decided to use the asymmetric encryption to solve this problem but I am having a hard time to understand how to deal with private keys.

I generate a private and public key on server side and encrypt the messages using the private key and store them in my mongoDB database. As much as I have figured, you give public key to everyone but you should not share private key yet messages can be decrypted only using private key as [this article](https://www.techtarget.com/searchsecurity/definition/asymmetric-cryptography) suggests.

> A public key is a cryptographic key that can be used by any person to
> encrypt a message so that it can only be decrypted by the intended
> recipient with their private key.
>
> When someone wants to send an encrypted message, they can pull the
> intended recipient's public key from a public directory and use it to
> encrypt the message before sending it. The recipient of the message
> can then decrypt the message using their related private key.

yet obviously client must be able to decrypt the encrypted message so it can show it to user.

Now we are in a situation where:

- the user must have the private key to decrypt the information.
- the private key should not be passed around as comments on [this post](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/101560/how-to-securely-send-private-keys) suggest

How should one deal with this contradiction?

Comment: Server have a private & a public key, and the user have a private & a public key. Sender encrypts with receivers public key and receiver decrypts with his private key.

Comment: Exactly. This is why many organisations keep the keys on the server, because you can't trust the end user device. Holding the key (for example) in Javascript to manually decrypt messages leaves a significant window of attack if the end user device is compromised in any way.

Comment: https://security.stackexchange.com/ may be a better place to ask this question.

Comment: @EbbeM.Pedersen I see. Now this is understandable.

Comment: @Martin Sure. Will do. I somehow got my answer though.